# How to replace a file with another file of same name which has new content in PHP?

Tags: php, file

I am new to PHP. In my application user when clicks for PDF, a copy on his name will be stored in a server. Next time, when he wants another PDF of different data, even that also will be stored on the same name in the server. I want to replace the old copy with the new PDF. Please tell me how to solve it. Thank You.

Comment: can you please remove code tags? it's impossible to read...

Comment: You should probably show some code

Comment: Why do you want to reuse filenames? THis will cause nothing but problems, especially with browsers with broken caching mechanisms.

Comment: $fileName = $UserName.'_Invoice.pdf';
$pdf->Output($fileName);  Here, when the user clicks for PDF of invoice, the copy will be generated into his server. Next time when he wants to have other invoice which will be created on same name should be overwritten.

Comment: I don't really understand, what's you goal? Do you want to store a copy of the last downloaded version on the server?

Comment: No Ern, I just want to keep latest invoice PDF only. No more PDFs should be there.

Answer (score 2):

Use `copy($source, $dest)` and the destination will always be overwritten if it exists.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 2):

Billy Moon's answer will work, but you can also use `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()`.

Heres how one might do that:

```
file_put_contents('user_file_new.pdf', file_get_contents('user_file_old.pdf'));
```

Comment: you can eat errors with `@` so `@copy($source, $dest);` will fail silently.

Comment: Although it is always good to know `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`. They are so versatile, very handy for scraping for example, where you can get a file, modify it, then save it. I don't think you can do that with copy :)

Comment: Heh, I Haven't used `fopen` in months. :)

Comment: Thank you all of you guys. Its done. I am deleting the existing file if exists and then creating a new one with same name. Here is my code.  `$fileName = $UserName.'_Invoice.pdf';
            if(file_exists($fileName))
              unlink($fileName);     
            $pdf->Output($fileName);`